# Volumes between Host and Container

Tags: docker, containers, host

I use Windows and I have a problem with this commando line.

> docker run --name website -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx

Docker: Error response from daemon: Conflict. The container name "/website" is already in use by container "9d253156c8179f6b3fe5b7997c504b71db2d8d6c24af3e5b4edbfe0d844d3d02". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

Comment: This has nothing to do with volumes. There's another container named "website". Either remove that container or use a different name.

Comment: As wrote @ElmoVanKielmo you have to remove the container named "website". You can use: 'docker rm -rf website'

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes#a-docker-cheat-sheet "Remove one or more specific containers
" section